# dependent multi object validation in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-validation

Each "time range" entry of the TimeClass is dependent on each other.

They cannot overlap and start_time < end_time.

models.py

```
class Xyz(models.Model):
    ...   

class TimeRangeClass(models.Model)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    xyz = models.ForeignKey(Xyz)
    # other fields here

    def clean(self):
        # Here I loop through TimeRangeClass.objects.all() and 
        # check for conflicts through my custom "my_validator_method".
        # If there is a conflict I throw an error
        #(I've since modified it to just be one single query as per Titusz advice)             
        for each in TimeRangeClass.objects.filter(xyz=self.xyz).exclude(id=self.id):
            my_validator_method(start_time1=self.start_time, 
                                end_time1=self.end_time, 
                                start_time2=each.start_time, 
                                end_time2=each.end_time)
```

admin.py

```
from .models import TimeRangeClass, Xyz
class TimeRangeClassInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TimeRangeClass
    extra = 3

@admin.register(Xyz)
class Xyz(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = []
    inlines = [TimeRangeClassInLine]
```

Problem: I can edit/add multiple TimeRangeClass's at once through the admin. But given that the models.Model clean method only evaluates 1 change at a time I can't validate multiple edits against each other.

Example:

1. Save an Entry1 & Entry2 without conflict
2. Change Entry2 to produce a validation error
3. Adjust Entry1 (instead of #2) so they do not overlap
4. This doesn't register because neither changes are written to the db.

I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: You should give a more concrete explanation of the problem.
Where/How do you change Entry #2? From the Admin interface, from view or a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints on the problem:

You should not iterate over the full table when checking for overlapping rows. Just filter for the problematic rows... something like:

```
overlaps = TimeRangeClass.objects.filter(
    Q(start_time__gte=self.start_time, start_time__lt=self.end_time) | 
    Q(end_time__gt=self.start_time, end_time__lte=self.end_time)
)
```

`overlaps` is now a queryset that evaluates when you iterate over it and only returns the conflicting objects.

If you are using Django with postgres you should check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#datetimerangefield.

Once you have the conflicting objects you should be able to change their start and end times within the function and save the changes. Model.save() will not automatically call the model.clean() method. But be aware, if you save an object from the Django admin it **will** call the model.clean() method before saving.

So something like that:

```
def clean():
    overlaps = TimeRangeClass.overlaps.for_trc(self)
    for trc_object in overlaps:
        fixed_object = fix_start_end(trc_object, self)
        fixed_object.save()
```

If you feel brave you should also read up on transactions to make the mutation of multiple objects in the database all succeed or all fail and nothing in between.

```
def clean():
    with transaction.atomic():
        # do your multi object magic here ...
```

**Update on clarified question:**

If you want to validate or pre/process data that comes from admin inlines you have to hook into the corresponding `ModelAdmin` method(s). There are multiple ways to approach this. I guess the easiest would be to override [ModelAdmin.save_fromset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset). Here you have access to all the inlineforms before they have been saved.

Comment: Thank you for the advise to use Q() instead of looping over the queryset. I am not sure why I decided to loop in this case, as I do use a similar query in other cases.

Comment: I briefly looked at the documentation for transaction.atomic(). Would this allow me to compare not yet saved variables for the clean method?

Comment: What do you mean by not yet saved variables? Where would your *not yet saved variables* come from? You are comparing the new eventually unsaved TimeRangeClass instance against existing instancances that you loaded into Memory via your queryset.

Comment: I use the TimeRangeClass as an inline for another model in the admin. Hence I am able to modify/add more than one TimeRangeClass at once. 

But I am only able to assess one TimeRangeClass at once through the clean method.

Comment: Thank you, ModelAdmin.save_fromset seems to be exactly what I am looking for.